# Local-machine Kubernetes service unreachable by pods

Tags: kubernetes

Followed this guide to starting a local-machine kubernetes cluster:
http://kubernetes.io/v1.0/docs/getting-started-guides/docker.html

I've created various pods with .yaml files and everything works, I can access nginx and mysql using container IPs (in the 172.17.x.x range, with docker0), however when I create services, service IPs are in the 10.0.0.x range, unreachable from other containers.

Isn't kube-proxy supposed to create iptables rules automatically, providing access to containers behind the service IP? No iptables changes are happening, and other containers can't reach services. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tim, I did run it again using your steps, no difference, didn't work, however today I switched to the version 1.1 docs here:

http://kubernetes.io/v1.1/docs/getting-started-guides/docker.html

and also switched container versions, currently using:

gcr.io/google_containers/etcd:2.2.1

gcr.io/google_containers/hyperkube:v1.1.1

Lo and behold...it works!!! Containers can now talk to services!
Thanks for the responses

Answer (score 1):

I just ran through this (slightly out of date) doc.  What I found is that it works if you replace the `hyperkube:v0.21.2` with `hyperkube:v1.0.7` in the 2 "docker run" lines, and replace `0.18.2` with `1.0.7` in the kubectl download URL.

I have offered a pull-request to update this doc.  Sorry for the trouble.

Comment: No luck - same symptoms. I've got pods talking to services on GKE, but not on the local-only dev system. Container to endpoints works, but not container to service IP.  Able to ping out to www from all containers. Is there a requisite set of command options when running docker for kubernetes? Using /usr/bin/docker -d -p /run/docker.pid --icc=true --ip-forward=true --iptables=true

Comment: https://gist.github.com/thockin/3a8043ce6129a44af530

I just ran through it again on a brand new VM.  Can you trace my steps and see if any piece is different?